# How do I create a lookup relationship that populates email instead of 'User'

Tags: lookup-filter

How the scenario should work:

A required field on opportunities that a user must select from a predefined list of approvers (they just have a flag on their user for department approver) before I use their email address in a custom button.

Current setup:

A field called Approver which is a lookup field that lets you select from a list of people who have the flag.

Issue:

The lookup populates 'Approver' with the actual user relationship so when I try to use it as an email address is doesn't work.

So my question is what's the best way to do it? How can I display the email address not the user? So I may use it within a button as Opportunity.Approver__c and get the email address value.

Thanks! Any best practices welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference `Opportunity.Approver__r.Email` to get the value of Email from the related User record.